# What's the fastest way to allow a user to pick one or more photos from his library to edit them in the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

Goal:

- Allow user to select one or more images from his photo library.
- Get an NSArray of selected UIImage objects or copy the files to a folder like /Documents.

[singingAtom has given a great answer as to how to use UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110470/how-to-allow-the-user-to-pick-a-photo-from-his-camera-roll-or-photo-library), but it returns only one image. How could this be extended such that the user can pick multiple images at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do it with the UIImagePickerController, instead you will have to use ALAssetLibrary in order to get the users photos and display them, then create your own controls to allow the user to pick more than one image...Here is a ref [ALASsetLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)