# How To Access Camera & Camera Roll Objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ipod

I am making a Universal iOS Application which needs to access the camera and the camera roll. How would i go about this? I have no code to show yet because the app is mainly based around this.

Comment: `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: check out this link : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389375/iphone-xcode-camera-integration-tutorials][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389375/iphone-xcode-camera-integration-tutorials

Comment: By using google and showing some research effort and reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Answer (score 38):

This answer relevant on physical device ONLY!

Access Camera:

```
- (void)takePhoto {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Access Camera Roll:

```
- (void)selectPhoto {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

Implementing the Delegate Methods of UIImagePickerController:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

And This:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Source code [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply as well. I will try the code now :)

Comment: The 3rd block of code there gets an error saying "Property imageView not found on object of type "ViewController *"". Other than that no errors

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare delegate UIImagePickerControllerDelegate  in .h file

and use this code to open camera.

```
// Pick image from camera

- (IBAction)captureImage:(id)sender
{   
    if (! [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *deviceNotFoundAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Device" message:@"Camera is not available"
                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [deviceNotFoundAlert show];

    } else {

        UIImagePickerController *cameraPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        cameraPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        cameraPicker.delegate =self;
        // Show image picker
        [self presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably this.

Here is the UIImagePickerController Class Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Here is overall camera programming and a useful document for you.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I will check these out :)