# How to copy an Image programmatically to an asset catalog

Tags: swift, ios8

I use the imagePickerController to choose an image from the camera roll. I would like to copy that image to an asset catalog like Images.xcassets. How can you do that?

Comment: Your question, as it is currently written, is likely to get closed. It's too similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991749/how-to-access-camera-camera-roll-objective-c Try to narrow the question down to a problem you encounter in an attempt to do this.

Comment: @Marien: as far as I know, `*.xcassets` are facilities provided to ease the development, but are not supposed to be compiled *within* the application. Could you please explain why do you need your images to be compiled specifically in an image catalog?

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks very much for your response and the fact that you think I know IOS development to some extent ;-) unfortunately I'm a total newbie. I'm working on a memory game which is bundled with some images to get started. But I thought it would be nice to let the user choose selfies from his  photo roll to make his own game. And because I'm a newbie I m looking for a way to copy chosen pictures to   Images.xcassets because I don't know anything else yet .

Answer (score 0):

Image `xcassets` are nothing more than a collection of images coupled with a specific file/directory organisation, and a JSON catalog, so there is nothing difficult in principle in creating them:

1. create an appropriate directory structure (I will refer to splash images, as they are the one I have more experience about):

---

```
myimages.xcassets/
myimages.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage
```

---

2. put your images in it
3. create an appropriate JSON catalog (spoiler: [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html)) and again, my example is about splash images:

---

```
"images": [
    {
        "scale": "2x",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "minimum-system-version": "7.0",
        "filename": "launch_seed_ipad_portrait.png",
        "idiom": "ipad",
        "extent": "full-screen"
    },
    [... etc ...]
}
```

and that's it. Point is, as bundles, image catalogs are more a facility provided to ease image organisation *from the Xcode project* (for instance, I created them in a context of project automation), and not something meant to be compiled *within the app*, so your question looks a bit like asking:

- how can I create a xib from code
- how can I put together a bundle from an app
- etc

all operations that can be carried on, if with some considerable effort, but are unlikely to do much good (either because the app cannot use the result, or there are more convenient alternatives).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT:

No the app assets, but you could save the image in "Document":

```
let dirPath = dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
let imagePath = (dirPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("IMAGE.EXT")
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
do
{
    try fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(imagePath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
}
catch _
{
}
if let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: DATA)//OR YOUR SOURCE
{
    var imageData: NSData! = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    if imageData == nil
    {
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100)
    }
    if imageData == nil
    {
        //DO SOMETHING..
    }

    imageData!.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)
}
```

And then load with:

```
if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(imagePath)
{
    return UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
}
```

That works for me, hope it helps!