# How to access photo gallery within iOS (objective c) app to pick photo while sharing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

There was an answer which lets an app select photos by opening the photo gallery  [How To Access Camera & Camera Roll Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991749/how-to-access-camera-camera-roll-objective-c) . But I want the new photo picking feature like whatsapp where we don't need to pick the photo from the gallery but while sharing there is a camera view and a view which lets you select photos in your album from the app itself . How would I populate the list of pictures within my app?

Something like this instagram sharing option http://www.iclarified.com/images/news/51645/244140/244140.jpg

Comment: While taking camera from the mobile do want to select the photos from photo libraray?

Comment: something like this http://www.iclarified.com/images/news/51645/244140/244140.jpg

Comment: I have never seen this before.First time I see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the Answer ! 
It's the new Photos framework . 
Uses assets to find the contents of photos .

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/

Answer (score 0):

An instance of ALAssetsLibrary provides access to the videos and photos that are under the control of the Photos application.

The library includes those that are in the Saved Photos album, those coming from iTunes, and those that were directly imported into the device. You  will use to retrieve the list of all asset groups and to save images and videos into the Saved Photos album.

[ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController) is an Example project for getting all the photos in the iPhone Photo Album.

Comment: Just now i tried this. but its shows like a default ImagePickerController. its use to customize

Comment: Do we need to customize that?

Comment: This still opens a photo gallery from the app , Doesn't really portray all photos within the app .

Comment: check the code not like that. first time we need to access permission.ALAsset Library using to manuall get the all images. "Check the  Viewcontroller --- ELCAlbumPickerController"